# Problem with breadth first algorithm in Python

Tags: python, breadth-first-search

[Edited] I'm trying to solve a problem in Python with the Breadth First Algorithm. I've created a Class to generate children nodes from a given one (and I know that this works properly because I've tested to call this generator with another solver code). So, my problem must be in this short lines of code:

```
def bfs(self, node):
        queue=[]
        visited_nodes=[]
        memory_use = len(visited_nodes)

        queue.append(node)
        is_solution=False

        while not is_solution:
            if len(queue)==0:
                print('Unsolvable board!')
                is_solution=True
            
            else:
                s=queue.pop(0)
                visited_nodes.append(s)
                
                if s.isWinningState():
                    is_solution=True
                    print('Winning state achieved.')
                    self.showPath(s)
                     print('Max memory usage: ', memory_use)
                else:
                    children = s.generateChildren()#deque with all possible states/nodes
                    if len(children) > 0:
                        for child in children:
                            if child not in visited_nodes:
                                queue.append(child)
```

it takes like 1 second to solve, despite not returning the correct number of visited nodes.

With the first code provided it just runs forever (I´ve killed the terminal 15 minutes after). Can someone help me figuring out what´s wrong in here?

Thanks

Comment: What *is* your problem?

Comment: Someone will certainly help you if you tell what is wrong!

Comment: It doesn't return any error. Just keeps processing for too long and I have to kill the terminal.

Comment: Do you mean it runs infinitely, or just very long? Can you please provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

when you are traversing children you should not append the child to the visited_nodes.

also before while you should just append the node to queue
after poping from the queue append the node to the visited_nodes

```py
def bfs(self, node):
        queue=[]
        visited_nodes=[]
        memory_use = len(visited_nodes)

        queue.append(node)

        while queue:
            s=queue.pop(0)
            visited_nodes.append(s)

            if self.finalStateAchieved:
                return
            if s.isWinningState():
                print('Winning state achieved.')
                self.showPath(s)
                self.finalStateAchieved = True
                print('Max memory usage: ', memory_use)
            else:
                children = s.generateChildren()#list with all possible states/nodes
                if len(children) > 0:
                    for child in children:
                        if child not in visited_nodes:
                            queue.append(child)
```

Comment: I understand! But some how, this doesn't work also.

Comment: specify an example with your output